# Using ASP.net WebAPI 2, how can I return some custom JSON along with a Datatable result

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I've been playing around with FB3 and WebAPI2 and it's coming along ok. I have been able to fill a DataTable from the database and return JSON pretty easily. Here's a sample of what the returning JSON looks like:

**CURRENTLY:**

```
[
  {
     ID: 10016,
     CREATED: "2016-08-24T21:35:45",
     MODIFIED: "2016-08-24T21:35:48",
     KEYNAME: "TEST"
  },
  {
     ID: 10017,
     CREATED: "2016-08-24T21:36:38",
     MODIFIED: "2016-08-24T21:36:41",
     KEYNAME: "TESTINT",
  }
]
```

However, now that I know how this is done, I would like to add some other information that I would gather during the process. The resulting JSON should look like the following:

**REQUIRE:**

```
[
   Meta: {
     status: "OK",
     message: "All's Well"
   },
   Data: {
     ID: 10016,
     CREATED: "2016-08-24T21:35:45",
     MODIFIED: "2016-08-24T21:35:48",
     KEYNAME: "TEST"
   },
   {
     ID: 10017,
     CREATED: "2016-08-24T21:36:38",
     MODIFIED: "2016-08-24T21:36:41",
     KEYNAME: "TESTINT",
    }
 ]
```

The code to get the first JSON result looks like the following:

```
    [Route("PerformSelectOnSettings")]
    [HttpGet]
    // GET: Connect/TestDBConnection
    public IHttpActionResult PerformSelectOnSettings()
    {

        Connection selectconnection = new Connection(fbconndetails.DBHost, string.Concat(fbconndetails.DBPath, fbconndetails.DBFile), Convert.ToInt32(fbconndetails.DBPort), fbconndetails.DBUser, fbconndetails.DBPassword, fbconndetails.DBConnectionLifeTime, fbconndetails.DBPooling, fbconndetails.DBMinPoolSize, fbconndetails.DBMaxPoolSize);
        DataTable result = new DataTable();



        string sqlcmd = "select * from settings";

        using (selectconnection.fbconnect)
        {

            try
            {
                selectconnection.fbconnect.Open();
                FbTransaction fbtrans = selectconnection.fbconnect.BeginTransaction();
                FbCommand fbcmd = new FbCommand(sqlcmd, selectconnection.fbconnect, fbtrans);

                using (FbDataReader fbsqlreader = fbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result.Load(fbsqlreader);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ExceptionsLogByFile logger = new ExceptionsLogByFile();
                        logger.LogException(e);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionsLogByFile logger = new ExceptionsLogByFile();
                logger.LogException(ex);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            selectconnection.fbconnect.Close();
            return Json(result);

        }


    }
```

At this point though, I'm really lost on how to add that first part to the JSON result. I've done some researching but I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for.

Any links / help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: are you using a model class to bind the data?

Comment: create the data structure you want. It's just another `POCO` with two properties.

Comment: Thank you @AmitKumarGhosh I did my research regarding POCO and created my own data structure, passing through the DataTable built through the query. Everything works as expected. Funnily enough, I was halfway there last night but I pulled back from that implementation because I was unsure. Really appreciate the hint.

Comment: @RachitGupta I'm not using a model class to bind the data.

Answer (score 3):

Is that Expected Json valid? I think it should be like:

```
{
    "Meta": {
        "status": "OK",
        "message": "All's Well"
    },
    "Data": [{
        "ID": 10016,
        "CREATED": "2016-08-24T21:35:45",
        "MODIFIED": "2016-08-24T21:35:48",
        "KEYNAME": "TEST"
    }, {
        "ID": 10017,
        "CREATED": "2016-08-24T21:36:38",
        "MODIFIED": "2016-08-24T21:36:41",
        "KEYNAME": "TESTINT"
    }]
}
```

A Json object with two properties - Meta and Data, where Data is array.

You can validate your json here - http://jsonlint.com/

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to add Meta details to the result (which is your data array). If that is the case, you can go for anonymous type:

```
 var data = new {
                   Meta = new { Status = "OK", Message = "All's well" },
                   Data = result
                 }

return Ok(data);
```

Comment: You are correct, what I posted originally was copied from my Chrome browser with a JSONView extension enabled. What you posted is the correct formatting (which I do get when I view it in other browsers).

Comment: @CSharpNewb - So if I understood your problem correctly, the result in return Json(result); is the Data array and you need to add meta data as well? Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are right, although the order I needed was Meta first and then the Data array, which is from the DataTable. I didn't go down the route of an anonymous type (although I'm certain that would work). Instead, I made a new class that was defined as a Meta object (with Status and Message) and a Data object that was a DataTable type. Then I passed the Meta details and the DataTable through that new class and returned it as JSON and let the WebAPI do the work of building the JSON string. Worked perfectly and passed the JSONLINT test as well!

Comment: @CSharpNewb - that works; just that I thought of avoiding a wrapper class for this. Thus said, if your Meta class is to get the status and status message of api call, then you could avoid that class. If you check the response header of return Ok() you could see what you are looking for. In case of error, you could return   BadRequest("Custom Message Here"); This is the standard way in case this was your intention